# Best way to store data with small differences for collective analysis

Tags: csv

I have a **collection of CSV files** each containing data about the same topic, but **with small differences**. For example units carrying out a job might in one file be identified by one field, in the other by two. Others again might include a marking field for urgend jobs, others not (there it has to be created during analysis). However, the overall information is the same. One important aspect is that the data contains subsets that are identified by IDs like a job ID and data for all related tasks.

Since the collection of files is constantly growing I like to **consolidate all the data in one database**. This would also allow comparing the different datasets. I was looking at NoSQL DBs like Mongo DB that was recommended to me due to the differences in structure of the data. So, summarizing the situation I see two choices:

1. (Keep the structure) Storing the data as it is in a NoSQL DB (if possible). My concern regarding this solution is if the mentioned job / task structure can be modeled with this appropriately.
2. (Loose original data) Defining a structure for the data and restructuring the data before saving it in the DB. The downside of this is obviously the restructuring. Especially since I like to store the data as pure as possible to ensure analysis results are reproducible from the original data.

**I am doing my analysis with R.** So, my question is what is your experience with either of the two versions and do you have a recommendation.

UPDATE:
As mentioned, analysis is done with R. So the database should at least be queried from inside R in the manner that both jobs as well as related tasks need to be retrieved. Regarding analysis: These are not very complex. As mentioned the main structure of the data is such that it contains data about jobs with different tasks related to each job. So, regular analytic steps to do are:

- Computing summary statistics for each job from the tasks.
- Adding markers for **both jobs and tasks** to identify different categories.
- Computing summary statistics for different categories.
- Computing time differences within a task (from several timestamps), between tasks and between jobs.

Comment: Good choices of data representation and storage depend on how the data will be queried and analyzed.  Since you have provided little information about the latter, it will be difficult for anyone to provide an objective, useful answer.  If you are not contemplating statistical analyses, you might want to migrate these questions (after suitably improving them) to another SE site such as [su] or [so].

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Advice of how to improve the question is highly appreciated since I know it's still rather vague. However, improvements will be made and I'll also consider moving the question.